# "You don't have bcrypt-ruby installed in your application." But in my opinion I have too many version of it ;) (Hartl tutorial 6.3)

Tags: ruby-on-rails, rspec, rubygems

I am learning by Hartl Tutorial and I needed to install geb bcrypt-ruby. I added it to Gemfile

```
    gem 'rails', '4.0.0.rc2'
    gem 'bootstrap-sass', '2.3.2.0'
    gem 'sprockets', '2.11.0'
    gem 'bcrypt-ruby', '3.1.2'
```

Everything seemed OK, but if I started run rspec spec/ then I got error:

> You don't have bcrypt+ruby installed in your application. Please add it to your Gemfile and rund bundle install
>   D:/RoR/RailsInstaller/Ruby1.9.3/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/bundler-1.3.5/lib/bundler/rubygems_integration.rb:224:in 'block in replace_gem':can't activate bcrypt-ruby <~>~3.0.0), already activated bcrypt-ruby-3.1.5-x86-mingw32. Make sure all dependencies are added to Gemfile. (Gem::LoadError)

In Gemfile lock there are lines:

```
    bcrypt (3.1.7-x86-mingw32)
    bcrypt-ruby (3.1.5-x86-mingw32)
      bcrypt (>= 3.1.3)
```

I tried delete Gemfile.lock and generate new one but with no help. My ruby version is 1.9.3p429 and rails 4.0.0.rc2. My operation system is 64bit Win7

Any good advice is warmly welcome ;)

Full error:

```
    D:\Projects\sample_app>rspec spec\
    You don't have bcrypt-ruby installed in your application. Please add it to your
    Gemfile and run bundle install
    D:/RoR/RailsInstaller/Ruby1.9.3/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/bundler-1.3.5/lib/bundler/rubygems_integration.rb:224:in `block in replace_gem': can't activate bcrypt-ruby (~> 3.0.0), already activated bcrypt-ruby-3.1.2-x86-mingw32. Make sure all dependencies are added to Gemfile. (Gem::LoadError)
    from D:/RoR/RailsInstaller/Ruby1.9.3/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/activemodel-4.0.0.rc2/lib/active_model/secure_password.rb:47:in `has_secure_password'
    from D:/Projects/sample_app/app/models/user.rb:7:in `<class:User>'
    from D:/Projects/sample_app/app/models/user.rb:1:in `<top (required)>'
    from D:/RoR/RailsInstaller/Ruby1.9.3/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/activesupport-4.0.0.rc2/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:228:in `require'
    from D:/RoR/RailsInstaller/Ruby1.9.3/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/activesupport-4.0.0.rc2/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:228:in `block in require'
    from D:/RoR/RailsInstaller/Ruby1.9.3/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/activesupport-4.0.0.rc2/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:213:in `load_dependency'
    from D:/RoR/RailsInstaller/Ruby1.9.3/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/activesupport-4.0.0.rc2/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:228:in `require'
    from D:/RoR/RailsInstaller/Ruby1.9.3/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/activesupport-4.0.0.rc2/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:329:in `require_or_load'
    from D:/RoR/RailsInstaller/Ruby1.9.3/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/activesupport-4.0.0.rc2/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:462:in `load_missing_constant'
    from D:/RoR/RailsInstaller/Ruby1.9.3/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/activesupport-4.0.0.rc2/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:183:in `const_missing'
    from D:/Projects/sample_app/spec/models/user_spec.rb:3:in `<top (required)>'
    from D:/RoR/RailsInstaller/Ruby1.9.3/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/rspec-core-2.13.1/lib/rspec/core/configuration.rb:819:in `load'
    from D:/RoR/RailsInstaller/Ruby1.9.3/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/rspec-core-2.13.1/lib/rspec/core/configuration.rb:819:in `block in load_spec_files'
    from D:/RoR/RailsInstaller/Ruby1.9.3/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/rspec-core-2.13.1/lib/rspec/core/configuration.rb:819:in `each'
    from D:/RoR/RailsInstaller/Ruby1.9.3/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/rspec-core-2.13.1/lib/rspec/core/configuration.rb:819:in `load_spec_files'
    from D:/RoR/RailsInstaller/Ruby1.9.3/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/rspec-core-2.13.1/lib/rspec/core/command_line.rb:22:in `run'
    from D:/RoR/RailsInstaller/Ruby1.9.3/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/rspec-core-2.13.1/lib/rspec/core/runner.rb:80:in `run'
    from D:/RoR/RailsInstaller/Ruby1.9.3/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/rspec-core-2.13.1/lib/rspec/core/runner.rb:17:in `block in autorun'
```

Comment: you need to install development kit for windows https://github.com/oneclick/rubyinstaller/wiki/development-kit from here then you try `gem install bcrypt-ruby`

Comment: The bcrypt-ruby gem has changed its name to just bcrypt. Instead of installing 'bcrypt-ruby', you should install 'bcrypt'. Please update your dependencies accordingli.

How I should update these dependencies?

Comment: bcrypt and bcrypt-ruby both gems are exists think which you want to use http://rubygems.org/gems/bcrypt-ruby

Comment: As I am really newbie in RoR area and all what I try right now is to follow Hartl tutorial step by step then I want that bcrypt-ruby 3.1.2 would be correctly installed and `rspec spec/` would pass the tests :)

Comment: OK - found finally solution myself : Gemfile should have `gem 'bcrypt-ruby', '~>3.0.0'`.

Answer (score 0):

For this error I found that deleting the dependency for version from the `/lib/active_model/secure_password.rb` works just fine.

Just make sure to add it back when moving to production so that you don't get other errors later

Answer (score 0):

I fixed this error by editing the gem version in

> /lib/active_model/secure_password.rb

gem 'bcrypt-ruby', '3.0.1' to gem 'bcrypt-ruby', '3.1.5'

**snippet**

```
begin
              gem 'bcrypt-ruby', '3.1.5'
              require 'bcrypt'
            rescue LoadError
              $stderr.puts "You don't have bcrypt-ruby installed in your application. Please add it to your Gemfile and run bundle install"
              raise
            end
```

Answer (score 0):

I had the same issue. I did the following and it works again

1. remove `bcrypt` from Gemfile
2. run `bundle install`
3. add `bcrypt` back
4. run `bundle install`